# Webpack module rule test: Match files that contain a specific parameter

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, urlloader, webpack-loader

I want to display some specific images as data-uri instead of linking to the image location. For that I'm using the url-loader.

Here's my HTML (pug template):

```
img.loading(:src="require('@/images/spinner.png?inline')")
```

And my webpack related config:

```
     {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)\?inline$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 135000,
          name: 'img/[name].[hash].[ext]',
          esModule: false
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'img/[name].[hash].[ext]',
          esModule: false
        },
```

The other images load fine, but the inline don't. Can I use those sort of parameters in the filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`resourceQueries` may be the best bet:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
    resourceQuery: /inline/
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 135000,
      name: 'img/[name].[hash].[ext]',
      esModule: false
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'img/[name].[hash].[ext]',
      esModule: false
    }
```

Note that both rules will be processed as `image.jpg?inline` image will match both rules so you many have to set up a separate `resourceQuery`